# insert/update db using single function in play framework

Tags: java, insert, playframework

I'm using Play framework, I want set a value for a field through model class. I have a model

package models;

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Blob;
import javax.sql.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Date;

import play.db.jpa.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="tblrecord")
public class Tblrecord extends GenericModel{


    @Id
        @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="\"id\"")
    public Integer id;

    @Column(name="\"customer_id\"", nullable=false)
    public Integer customerId;

    @Column(name="\"record_type_id\"", nullable=false)
    public Integer recordTypeId;

    @Column(name="\"fields_id\"", nullable=false)
    public Integer fieldsId;

    @Column(name="\"field_values\"", nullable=false, length=21845)
    public String fieldValues;         
}
```

I want to insert into DB like this

```
public void setValueForField(String fieldName, String value)
{
this.fieldName = value;
}
```

Here if i pass

```
setValueForField("fieldValues", "myFieldValue")
```

Then it should update for the field fieldValues

I want to insert like this,Is this facility availbale in java or playframework by default by chance.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not available without using Java reflection as far as I know.